# Protection level (Modifiers) of controls change automaticlly in .Net

Tags: .net, winforms, modifier

My project is on .Net V2.0, some of controls are in public, when change form in design mode this controls changed to private. how can i fix this? thanks. When Modifier changed to private, in Property Tool Box Modifier property not show. many of controls go to 
below  section of form in picture 2.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I've seen this kind of total designer failure before.  As yet, never diagnosed by the victim.  You'll need to consider restoring the last working version from source control to recover from this.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are making the controls public by editing the `Designer.cs` file, there is a reason they put the warning in there that your changes will be lost.

The correct way is to mark the control's `Modifers` setting to `public` in design view from the properties menu for your control.

[image]

---

**EDIT:** Well I'll be damned, you don't have a modifiers option. Well, here is a workaround, create a property that is public that you control that can point at the private member.

```
public RadPageView pgvTabsPublic 
{
    get {return pgvTabs;}
}
```

Using this you can have other classes call `yourForm.pgvTabsPublic` and it will point them to the internal private `pgvTabs` member.

Comment: I changed in `Designer.cs` but after change the form, modifiers changed automaticly. In design Mode i can't select the control

Comment: Why can't you select the control? Does it not show up in the dropdown (where it says "**button1** System.Windows.Forms.Button" on my image)?

Comment: Yes, only can select from DropDown but in property list, Modifier don't be show.

Comment: So if you selected it from the dropdown list, `Modifers` does not show up under the list of settings you can set? I hate to say I don't believe you, but can you edit your original question and include a screenshot of the `Modifiers` option being missing?

Comment: add Picture of property tool box

Comment: @1mohammadi.ir I am sorry for not believing you, I have updated my answer with a workaround you can use.

Answer (score 0):

This problem for Version of telerik i use, before i use version 2012 and now use 2013,fix it and work it, thanks